# Parsing pipe delimited json output

Tags: python

I'd like to preface by saying that I'm VERY new to python so apologize if the answer to this is obvious. :) I have a python script does a couple of API calls and returns json data.  The output currently looks something similar to below:

IP Information is below:

```
{
  "id": 318283,
  "name": "Name",
  "type": "IP4Address",
  "properties": "VLAN=5|DeviceName=Device|Notes=This is a description address|Administration=Team that admins the system|Location-Code=Location|address=1.2.3.4|state=STATIC|"
}
```

IP Subnet Range Information is below:

```
{
  "id": 118836,
  "name": "VLAN Description",
  "type": "IP4Network",
  "properties": "Location-Code=Location|Notes=Description of the subnet|CIDR=1.2.3.0/25|allowDuplicateHost=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|pingBeforeAssign=disable|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|inheritDefaultDomains=true|defaultView=118346|inheritDefaultView=true|inheritDNSRestrictions=true|"
```

I'd like for the response to not have the "id" string and would like to split the various | delimited strings in properties into their own string so it looks like below:

```
{
  "id": 318283,
  "name": "Name",
  "type": "IP4Address",
  "properties":{
                "VLAN": “5”,
"DeviceName": “Device”,
"Notes": “Description”,
"Administration": “Admin team”,
"Location-Code": “Location”,
"Address": “1.2.3.4”,
"State": “STATIC”
  } 
}


{
  "id": 118836,
  "name": "Subnet name",
  "type": "IP4Network",
  "properties":{
"Location-Code": "Location",
"Notes": "Subnet description. ",
"CIDR": "1.2.3.0/25",
"allowDuplicateHost": "disable",
"inheritAllowDuplicateHost": "true",
"pingBeforeAssign": "disable",
"inheritPingBeforeAssign": "true",
"inheritDefaultDomains": "true",
"defaultView": "118346",
"inheritDefaultView": "true",
"inheritDNSRestrictions": "true"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to handle your pipe-separated properties:

```
a = { "id": 318283, "name": "Name", "type": "IP4Address", "properties": "VLAN=5|DeviceName=Device|Notes=This is a description address|Administration=Team that admins the system|Location-Code=Location|address=1.2.3.4|state=STATIC|" }
new_properties = {}
for key_val_pair in a['properties'].split("|"):
    if key_val_pair.strip() == "":
        continue
    key, val = key_val_pair.split("=")
    new_properties[key] = val
a["properties"] = new_properties

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 318283, 'name': 'Name', 'type': 'IP4Address', 'properties': {'VLAN': '5', 'DeviceName': 'Device', 'Notes': 'This is a description address', 'Administration': 'Team that admins the system', 'Location-Code': 'Location', 'address': '1.2.3.4', 'state': 'STATIC'}}
```